# how to view list of articles in publishing site?

Tags: publishing-site

In need to view list of article in publishing site with content. It's complicated by using layouts of pages. I find one not simple way - use only one layout and make xsl template for rendering only this one layout in list. But layouts very comfort tool for content representation and i'm want to save it. Have any ideas about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one way - setup XsltListViewWebPart, exprot it to SiteCollection by using Designer and past it to custom page layout.